# How do I round a number to another number but only when it is within .0001 of that value. ex round 5.999 to 6 but not 5.93 to 6?

Tags: rounding, rounding-error

Squareroot causing a long decimal that is not equal. for example 3.199999 does not equal 3.2.

I am asking the user to enter points to see if the form a triangle.  If the points form a triangle... the program determines what triangle is created.  The problem I am having is that when certain points are entered; the square root when finding a side length creates a number like 5.9999.  This causes issues when determining the triangle because the side lengths will show s1=5.9999 s2=5.9999 and s3=6.  when the program reads this it will say that it is an isoceles triangle but rather it should be an equilaterol triangle but is not because of square root issue. How can I fix this?

```
m = x1 - x2;
l = y1 - y2; 
j = x2 - x3; 
j2 = y2 - y3; 
w = x3 - x1; 
w2 = y3 - y1; 



if( abs((x2-x1)*(y3-y1)-(y2-y1)*(x3-x1)) == 0) 
{
    printf("Not a triangle");
}
else
{

    if(s1 == s2 && s2 == s3 && s1 == s3) 
    {
        printf("\nThis forms an equilateral triangle"); 
    }   
    else //if statement above is not true
    {
        if((s1 == s2 && s1 != s3) || (s1 == s3 && s2 != s1) || (s2 == s3 && s1 != s2)) 
        {
            printf("\nThis forms an isoceles triangle"); 
        }
        if(s1 != s2 && s2 != s3 && s1 != s3) 
        {
            printf("\nThis forms a scalene trianle"); 
        }
    }
}
    printf("\n\ns1:  %g\ns2: %g\ns3:  %g\n",s1, s2, s3);
```

}

I would like the output to show when s1=5.49999 s2=5.5 s3 = 5.5 to say that an equilateral triangle has been created and not an isoceles.  thanks for the help

Comment: Add .0001 to the number, and then do a `math.floor()` of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate this: 
newnumber = 0.0001 * round(10,000*number)

```
Examples: 
number = 5.9999    =>  newnumber = 6
number = 5.93      =>  newnumber = 5.93
number = 3.199999  =>  newnumber = 3.2
number = 5.999     =>  newnumber = 5.999
```

If you want the last example to be 6 then use 1,000 instead of 10,000 as factor in the formula above.
I don't know your programming language but assume you'll find the correct term for 'round'

Good luck!

Comment: Adding 0.0001 as suggested in a comment would work as well in most cases, but be carefully then with small values, e.g. if s1=0.0001 and s2=0.0002 then it's on the one hand the double but on the other hand within 0.0001. You might want to let it as is, but adding 0.0001 plus rounding would bring you 100% deviation. So you need to define precisely how you want to handle extreme triangles and if adding or the factor method is more convenient.